# hook_menu access argument returns 3 instead of data

Tags: hooks

I am trying to access an api that I wrote, with an access that is limited to administrators only.

My code is:

```
mymodule_menu() {
/**
 * Create api callback to return list of users in a give site
*/
  $items['api/v1/userslist'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_api_userslist',
    'access arguments' => array('administer permissions'),
    'delivery callback' => 'mymodule_json',
  );

  return $items;
```

this just return the value "3" for no reason.

If I remove access argument and put         `'access callback'   => TRUE`,
everything is working. So it is a problem with the permission.

Any ideas?

```
function mymodule_json($data) {
  if (isset($data['error'])) {
    drupal_add_http_header('Status', '400 Bad Request');
  }

  echo drupal_json_output($data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delivery callback is not right. The default delivery callback is [`drupal_deliver_html_page($page_callback_result)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7.x).

From that page:

> `$page_callback_result`: The result of a page callback. Can be one of:
>
> - NULL: to indicate no content.
> - An integer menu status constant: to indicate an error condition.
> - A string of HTML content.
> - A renderable array of content.

So there is no such thing as `$data['error']`. You are probably encoding the error code `3`.

In the default callback they catch integers as errors:

```
// Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string or array.
if (is_int($page_callback_result)) {
  ...
}
```

You might want to do the same:

```
function mymodule_json($data) {
  if (is_int($data)) {
    drupal_add_http_header('Status', '400 Bad Request');
  }

  echo drupal_json_output($data);
}
```

Comment: but why would this permission be an error?

Comment: If you do not have permission to view the page, Drupal will serve you a HTTP 403 Forbidden header. The `3` corresponds with [`MENU_ACCESS_DENIED`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_ACCESS_DENIED/7.x). However you did not properly check the error, so the 3 was sent straight to output.

Comment: but the user should have admin permissions

Comment: That is something I cannot check. Are you sure you have written `administer permissions` correctly? Try another permission? Did you change it later and forgot to flush the cache? I can only explain where the 3 is coming from.